# How many kWh to fully charge a battery?

Tags: power, batteries, battery-charging

If I have an 11.6 Ah 48 V battery, how many kWh does it take to fully charge it from empty? I calculated 556.8 Wh using the formula P = I * V  (11.6 * 48 / 1000), which works out to be 0.5568 kWh. Is that correct? Do you have to factor in the voltage and/or current of the charger at all?

Comment: What is the average rate of charge on the charger?

Comment: How do I determine that? It is a 48V 2A charger.

Comment: Your calculations are correct for a 100% efficient battery and charger. You will have losses to heat in both. You'd need to read the datasheets to get info on those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by computing just the energy that will be stored in the battery.  (11.6 Ah)(48 V) = 557 Wh = 0.557 kWh.

**However**, there are various losses along the way that are hard to quantify.

The Ah rating of the battery is what it can supposedly deliver.  It's what comes out, not what you have to put in to get that out.  No battery is 100% efficient, so you have to put more in than what you eventually get out.  The efficiency is hard to know, and is usually not specified well or at all by the manufacturer.  The charging sequence also makes a significant difference.  For example, if it ends with a "top off" slow charge, most of that energy won't be stored by the battery.

Then there is the efficiency of the power supply that generates the required voltage and current to charge the battery.

Overall, I would not expect more than half the energy into the charger to eventually come back out of the battery.  Therefore, I'd consider around 1 kWh the minimum required energy, but somewhat more is also quite possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you have calculated is the amount of energy that can be taken from the battery. That energy also needs to be stored in the battery by the charger, but there are losses in the battery and in the charger that need to supplied by the source during charging. There are also losses in the battery during use, so a battery that can deliver 557 Wh needs to have more than that stored to supply the losses during discharge. The required efficiency information is probably not available for specific batteries and chargers, but you may be able to find some basis to make an estimate if you search.